# KafkaConsumercontext class is deprecated. What is alternative to use?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using `Kafka 0.9.0.1`  ( kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1 is downloaded zip name).  For the consumer configuration, I am using `KafkaConsumerContext` and found that it is deprecated.

Tried searching many online resources to find alternate latest Class to replace KafkaConsumerContext but in vain.

can someone guide on what is the replacement for deprecated `KafkaConsumercontext`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `Kafka 2.11`? Kafka's latest version is `0.9.0.1`: https://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  My bad.. provided Scala compatible version instead of Kafka's verison. I have updated my post. Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look into https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Consumer.java

It uses `Properties` for configuration.